# .apk Application stopping unexpectedly when installed to emulator or phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

I've developed a component to have slideshow of the images in horizontal and vertical directions. the code is working fine when run from eclipse. I exported it and tried installin the .apk file to the emulator and also android phone. but the application force closes without displayin images. I'm **not getting errors in the logcat** also. 
The images were inserted from the res folder to the SQLite database and SDCard and read from there. What can be the cause for not fetching the images? How do I check for the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to edit AVD.In Hardware select the SD Card Support to yes.

Comment: Yes.I've selected SDCard option. Even from the database it is not reading the images. :(